# Random Image Display Order on Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

I am new to Javascript - I am trying to make images on a page reload in a different order every time a page is refreshed - so that you have a new website arrangement for every visit.

Similar to what is done here: [pauljung.co.uk](https://pauljung.co.uk)

The function used here is MathRandom which resizes images and places them in different positions on load - however I would like to know how exactly are the images called onto the HTML body of the page?

I've tried placing a spacer gif within the body and linking it to JS with id=picture, however this does not load all the images at once.

```html
<img src="images/spacer.gif" id="Picture" alt="some image">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#picture > img').each(function () {

        var randomXs = ["0px", "5%", "10%"];
        var randomX2s = ["0px", "0px", "0px", "5%"];
        var randomYs = ["200px", "50px", "100px", "150px", "250px", "300px"];
        var randomY2s = ["0px", "5%"];
        var widths = ["35%", "30%", "20%", "20%", "20%", "40%"];

        if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
            var randomXs = ["0px", "5%", "10%", "15%", "30%", "20%"];
            var randomX2s = ["0px", "0px", "0px", "5%"];
            var randomYs = ["200px", "50px", "-100px", "100px", "150px", "250px", "300px"];
            var randomY2s = ["0px", "5%"];
            var widths = ["20%", "30%", "20%", "15%", "20%", "25%", "20%"];
        }

        if ($(window).width() > 1600) {
            var randomXs = ["0px", "5%", "10%", "15%", "30%", "20%"];
            var randomX2s = ["0px", "5%"];
            var randomYs = ["200px", "50px", "-100px", "100px", "150px", "250px", "300px"];
            var randomX2s = ["0px", "0px", "0px", "0px", "5%"];
            var widths = ["35%", "30%", "22%", "20%", "18%", "17%", "23%", "10%", "12%", "15%", "15%", "11%", "13%"];
        }

        var randomX = randomXs[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomXs.length)];
        var randomX2 = randomX2s[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomX2s.length)];
        var randomY = randomYs[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomYs.length)];
        var randomY2 = randomY2s[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomY2s.length)];
        var width = widths[Math.floor(Math.random() * widths.length)];

        $(this).css('width', width);
        $(this).css('margin-right', randomX2);
        $(this).css('margin-left', randomX);
        $(this).css('margin-bottom', randomY);
        $(this).css('margin-top', randomY2);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers perform case sensitive search on elements

So an HTML ID is case sensitive.

The id '**Picture**' should be changed to '**picture**' in this case.

```
<img src="images/spacer.gif" id="picture" alt="some image">
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help - this still does not call the images within the 'images' directory into the html in random order, which is what I am trying to achieve. The math random code already resizes and places images in random order on the page however I need a way to load the images into the body of the page in random order. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: How are the images called into the html body?